# Typescript Method Similar to Watch()

Tags: typescript, proxy, watch, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am working with a map and I want to perform an action when I move the map (zoom in/out, move).
The map can be interacted with the mouse (drag, scroll, button click) and the keyboard, so I don't think creating a onClick is ideal.

The map object has a key-value that is [stationary]-Boolean and the stationary changes to False when the map is moving, and True when the map stops moving.
I want to have an a function be called automatically whenever map.stationary is changed back to True.
I first tried it with

```
map.watch("stationary", ()=>{
// function here
}
```

But I later found out that watch() is deprecated (and it is also causing me problems of being assigned multiple times when the map is changed to a different map, but that's a seperate story)

Upon research, proxies might be the answer, but I can't figure out how to set the proxy so that it is called everytime map.stationary changes back to True.

I have no idea how to set up the proxy to function the same way it did with watch().
Any kind of tip will be appreciated, thank you!

```
    let handler1 = {
      get(target, property, receiver) {
        if (target.stationary) {
          console.log("this is true");
        }
      },
    };
    let proxy1 = new Proxy(jmv.view, handler1);
```

The code I wrote only calls the console.log once on load, and isn't called after that, no matter how many times map.stationary changes back to True.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer after further research.
It was actually very simple.
I found that JS ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript supports .watch() and the solution to the duplication problem could be solved simply by creating a variable in the beginning, assign the .watch() to the variable, and remove() the variable if it was already assigned.

```
if (scaleWatch) {
  scaleWatch.remove();
}

scaleWatch = jmv.view.watch("stationary", () => {
  console.log("getScaleBar() is watching");
  scaleBarDiv.innerHTML = "";
  customScaleBar = new ScaleBar({
    container: scaleBarDiv,
    view: jmv.view,
    unit: "metric",
    style: "ruler",
  });
});
```